# Accessing Subclass Properties After Passing as The Superclass (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, class, parameter-passing, subclass, superclass

I've been searching for the answer for this, but I'm finding it very difficult to find answers to specific problems like this. It could be that I'm just not understanding something properly, but whatever it is, I Hope you can help! :)

I have a class named Panda that extends a class named Player.
I also have a class named Enemy that accepts a Player as a parameter.
The Enemy class actually need to access property of the Panda class, but since I want to create multiple classes that extend the Player class and will be passed to the Enemy class, Enemy accepts a parameter of the Player class.

However when I try to access anything that belongs to the Panda class but not the Player class it give me the 1119 error: access of possibly undefined property...

Why is this and How can I set up my code so that I can pass various classes that extends the Player class, and access their properties, without getting this 1119 error?

(Hmm. Subclasses, and Superclasses...I am using these terms right, right?)

---

These links help me the understand that answer below. Thank you for your help!

Constant var: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html

Type Casting: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing properties of the Panda class, you have to type cast:

```
private var _player:Player;

public Enemy(player:Player) {
  _player = player;
  const panda:Panda = _player as Panda;
  if (panda) {
    setPlayerIsPanda(panda);
  }
}

private function setPlayerIsPanda(panda:Panda):void {
  // do panda stuff
}
```